# Why is vector parametrization of a line perpendicular to the line itself?

Tags: orthogonality, parametrization

For a vector of parameters $p$, a line can be expressed as $p^T + k = 0$. The vector p is perpendicular to that line. I can picture an example of that (for instance vector $(\frac{-1}2, 1)$ is perpendicular to the line it defines $y = \frac{1}2x$). However, I cannot understand why.

Answer (score 0):

vector $ \vec{v} \in l \rightarrow \vec{v}\cdot \vec{p}=0 $ (dot product (scalar product) of vectors  is equals 0)

For example $ [\vec{v}= (2,1) \in l :y = \frac{1}{2}x ] \rightarrow [(2,1)\cdot (\frac{-1}{2}, 1) =  2\cdot (-\frac{1}{2})+ 1\cdot 1 = -1 + 1 = 0] $

Comment: I understand that, but why does it happen that the dot product is 0?

Comment: Because for perpendicular  vectors  dot product is equal 0

Comment: I also know that. However, I was looking for an explanation of why they happen to be perpendicular, i.e. why their dot product is 0, instead of just computing that dot product and conlcuding that it is equal to 0.

Comment: x\cdot y = |x||y|\cos(x,y)